# How do I enrich the right hand corner with the name of the file included

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, watermark

I'm including several `pdf` files with names like `R1.pdf` `R2.pdf`...`R22.pdf`
**and** I need to print the **name** of each such a file to the right hand corner
on **each** page of the file included. I mean that `R0.pdf` will have at each of its pages written in small letters `R0` at the top right hand side starting with first page. Next `R1.pdf` `R2.pdf` etc.

How could I achieve this goal ? BTW, I would be happy with the solution in which I would write a new command above each `includepdf` command.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\begin{document}

%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{sh1.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R0.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R1.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R2.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R3.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R4.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includepdf` can overlay a `picture` iirc. You might use that. See its manual for instructions (or wait a couple hours until I have the time to take a look).

Comment: @Skillmon I'll wait till you add a MWE. Thank you.

Comment: @Skillmon Please what is `iirc` ? It would be excelent if there would be **the correct title of each chapter/paper name** at the top right hand corner instead of the name of the pdf file ! If this is not possible then plese give me a MWE in which I would be able to insert my hand created string for this.

Comment: An acronym for "if I recall correctly". You'll have to be a patient for a couple more hours or so...

Comment: Use option `picturecommand` like this: `\includepdf[pages=-, picturecommand={\put(100,100){R0.pdf}}]{file.pdf}`

Comment: @AndreasMatthias I'll try your promising suggestion latter in this evening, I'm off my computer now. BTW, how could I rotate the string `R0.pdf` ? Will that string be visible on **all** pages ?

Comment: @AndreasMatthias What could I use as a parameter to `picturecommand` that would eventually print the **title** of each appropriate pdf, in this case `R0.pdf` ?

Comment: Well, now that you got an answer, I guess my MWE is no longer necessary :)

Comment: @Skillmon You are almost correct. But I have also asked 2 additional questions: how can I rotate my watermark by 90 degrees **and** how can I replace the string `R0.pdf` with the **title** of the corresponding paper.

Comment: @user2925716 both are covered by the answer.

Comment: @Skillmon I was reading comments while my browser didn't display the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use option `picturecommand` like this:

```
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  picturecommand={%
    \put(10,10){file.pdf}}
]{file.pdf}
```

Option `picturecommand` gives you a picture environment, so you are free to do whatever you want including rotating stuff:

```
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  picturecommand={%
    \put(10,10){\rotatebox{45}{file.pdf}}}
]{file.pdf}
```

If you want to print the title of a PDF you have to extract the title first. Using luatex this is not so difficult:

```
\newcommand\gettitle[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/figure')
    doc = pdfe.open(filename)
    info = pdfe.getinfo(doc)
    title = info['Title']
    tex.print(title)
  }}
```

Finally, use this macro inside `picturecommand`:

```
\includepdf[
  pages=1-2,
  picturecommand={%
    \put(10,10){\rotatebox{45}{\gettitle{file.pdf}}}}
]{file.pdf}
```

Comment: GREAT. I'm actually using `XeLaTeX.exe`. Could you kindly modify your answer appropriately ? So what is the equivalent of directlua in xelatex ?

Comment: \gettitle #1->\directlua 
                         {local filename = kpse.find_file("#1", 'graphic/fig...
l.24 ...\put(100,100){\gettitle{R0.pdf}}}]{R0.pdf}
                                                  
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on mergeSR.log.

Comment: @user2925716 I've no idea whether it's possible to write a `\gettitle` macro for xetex. AFAIK xetex does not have a primitive to get hold of the PDF title. Neither does luatex, but luatex provides the pdfe library with which you can step through the pdf and extract the title yourself.

Comment: David Carlisle will definitely know this if he hears about this question. Could you give him an invitation to this problem ?